# Developing a multi-database, one single interface system

Tags: node.js, mongodb

am currently developing an application using MongoDB and node js that works somewhat like a bitrix24 CRM system or monday.com, and I got stuck in the aspect of MongoDB database design where anytime new user signup on let say. yourapplication.com, a new domain, and database is created for this user so that the user has his own as user.yourapplication.com and anytime people visit user.yourapplication.com, they can easily signup and do lots of stuff on it.

Comment: do you have any initial project setup?

Comment: actually I will say a yes, I have this logistics application that I developed, and more than one company are interested in it, but any time it has an error, I will have to start editing the code for each company separately and it is a very bad experience

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think you would need each site to be its own database.  Could just separate the elements of each site, and its objects (including user details and stuff), into different collections within the same database.